# HTML table can only be displayed in Chrome but not Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

The table (see code below) can be fully displayed in the Chrome, but not in Safari, how to edit the code to make it work in Safari too?

```html
<table align="left" border="3" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 65%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:16px;">Payoff</span></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:16px;">Probability</span></td>
      <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:16px;">&nbsp;<strong>OR</strong>&nbsp;</span></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:16px;">Payoff</span></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:16px;">Probability</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:16px;"><strong>Win 3 times investment</strong></span></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:16px;"><strong>2/3</strong></span></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:16px;"><strong>Lose investment</strong></span></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:16px;"><strong>1/3</strong></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**In Safari**
[image]

**In Chrome**
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit this as runnable snippet? So others can see it ah real html, and not a bunch of images.

Comment: Right now I’m having hard time selecting it and pasting into some online html editor. Somehow I got all of my attention used by this silly question.

Comment: I’m on mobile, btw

Comment: Table looks the same in Safari both on desktop and mobile. I assume this is from a larger set of code. Is there a wrapper around the table?

Comment: Ok, you can see how much time it took me to do a simple op on mobile. Not all html editors, that can share, a mobile friendly. So I got this link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErzBOW

Comment: I made an edit with this link, so others can see html output. While in edit screen, I saw that the question, somehow, has run snippet button. Why I can’t see the button live? Is it some sort of review only option?

Comment: Same result for me on iPhone 8+ with Safari http://imgshr.com/7ace1345cb